Is the "Asshur" in Genesis 10:11 a place or a person?

Genesis 10:11 NKJV - From that land he went to Assyria and built Nineveh, Rehoboth Ir,
Calah,
Genesis 10:11 NIV - From that land he went to Assyria, where he built
Nineveh, Rehoboth Ir, Calah
Genesis 10:11 ESV - From that land he went into Assyria and built
Nineveh, Rehoboth-Ir, Calah, and
Genesis 10:11 NASB - From that land he went to Assyria, and built
Nineveh, Rehoboth-Ir, Calah,



Genesis 10:11 KJV - Out of that land went forth Asshur, and builded
Nineveh, and the city Rehoboth, and Calah,

The KJV translates this verse as “Out of that land went forth Asshur, and builded Nineveh, and the city Rehoboth, and Calah,” which suggests that Asshur went out and built these cities.
However, other translations interpret that it was Nimrod who went forth into Assyria (the land of Asshur) and built these cities.

Who built the cities?
What could explain the difference in mentioning “Asshur” that is unique to the King James Version?


The OP's question may be equivalently re-phrased as:
Is the "Asshur" in Gen 10:11 a place or a person?  The KJV follows (as in most places) the Clementine Vulgate text which follows the LXX.  The Hebrew could theoretically be translated either way.  However, the context demands that Asshur is, in this instance, a place, and thus it is Nimrod who built the named cities.
Ellicott comments as follows:

(11, 12) Out of that land went forth Asshur.—So the LXX., Syriac, and
Vulg.; but the Targum and most modern authorities rightly translate,
“Out of that land he went forth into Assyria.” We have here nothing to
do with Asshur the son of Shem (see Genesis 10:22), but are occupied
with Nimrod and the Hamites, who, after firmly establishing themselves
in Babylonia, subsequently extended their influence northward. This is
confirmed by the cuneiform inscriptions, which prove that the southern
portion of Mesopotamia was the chief seat of the Accadians, while in
Assyria they came at an early date into collision with the Shemites,
who drove them back, and ultimately subjugated them everywhere.

Indeed, even the 1611 KJV itself acknowledges this by noting it in the margin.  The NKJV has corrected this anomaly.  Barnes reaches a similar conclusion:

Out of that land came he forth to Asshur. - This may be otherwise
rendered, "out of that land came forth Asshur." The probabilities in
favor of the former translations are the following:

The discourse relates to Nimrod.

The words admit of it.

The word Asshur has occurred hitherto only as the name of a country.

Asshur, the person, was considerably older than Nimrod, and had probably given name to Asshur before Nimrod's projects began.

Asshur would have been as great a man as Nimrod, if he had founded Nineveh and its contiguous towns; which does not appear from the text.

"The beginning of his kingdom" implies the addition to it contained in these verses.

And the phrases "in the land of Shinar, out of that land," and the need of some definite locality for the second four cities, are in
favor of the former rendering.



I agree.

+1. I like the re-phrased question and have thus changed the question to reflect it. I found it interesting that that the Benson Commentary says: Out of that land went forth Asshur — He was the son of Shem, Genesis 10:22 : and, it seems that, not being able to endure Nimrod’s tyranny, who possessed himself of other men’s territories, (Chaldea, which Nimrod had seized upon, being Shem’s part,) he went away beyond Tigris, where he founded the empire of Assyria, whose chief city was Nineveh, Isaiah 23:13.

The problem is with translating Hebrew verb יָצָ֣א , which is the past (more precisely - perfect) tense for singular masculine subject, meaning he/it went (or he/it exited). Thus, without additional specification it may refer either to Assur/אַשּׁ֑וּר (meaning Assyria - a country/nation) or to Nimrod, who is the subject of the preceding verses.
The following verses hardly help to resolve this difficulty, as in 10:13 one seems to have switched from talking about people to speaking of Nations:

Egypt was the father of the Ludites, Anamites, Lehabites, Naphtuhites. (NIV)

Although it is possible that מִצְרַ֡יִם here is again not the name of a country (Egypt), but a proper name, as in

Mizraim was the ancestor of the Ludites, Anamites, Lehabites, Naphtuhites. (NLT)

It is not to exclude that the author/writer is deliberately ambiguous, as a matter of being poetic; or that they intend to stress that the personalities mentioned earlier were fathers of nations, and therefore equated in importance with the nations that follow in the latter verses.

I won't hazard an opinion as to the "real" answer here, but traditional Jewish readings hold that Asshur was a person in this case. The Jewish Encyclopedia article on Asshur states:

Asshur was one of the few pious men of the generation of the Tower of
Babel. In order to avoid participation in that sinful project, he left
the land of his fathers and settled in the neighborhood of Nineveh, in
reward for which action he received the cities mentioned in Gen. x.
11, 12.

Rashi's commentary on Genesis Rabbah 37

As soon as Asshur saw that his sons listened to Nimrod, rebelling
against the Omnipresent by building the Tower, he went forth out of
their midst (Genesis Rabbah 37:4).

Ashur was also the national deity of Assyria. Thus is it very hard to tell which came first, the deity, the city or the person.
